# Recover files from a running live Linux USB

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb

I have a live Linux USB (Elementary OS) that became unresponsive after I tried to download a huge file to disk.  The screen is now permanently in sleep mode and moving the mouse or keyboard won't wake it.  Putting a USB drive in and out causes the led on the live USB to flicker but that's it.

Is there anyway I can interface with the system at all? Or at least recover the files?

Comment: Can you `ssh` in, from another computer?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to another tty terminal ?

`Ctrl+Alt+F1` to `F6`.